# jquery creating events when mouseenter and mouseleave

Tags: jquery

I am trying to rock a simple image back and forth on a mouseover using jquery.
The image id is "img".

```
   $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#img").bind('mouseenter', function () {
            $('#img').rotate(43);  
        });
        $("img").bind('mouseleave', function () {
            $('#img').rotate(-43);              
        });
    });
```

When I do this the first rotate works but the second does not. Why is this? I can use the second by itself and it works as expected too. I just can't get both to work together. Iam using a library to rotate. If I sub alerts for the rotate I still can't the second to work.
Any suggestions?
TIA 
John

Comment: Try the [.hover function](http://api.jquery.com/hover/), allows you to bind functions for enter and leave very easily

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing you're using [this plugin](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-rotate/), and looking at the way it does the rotation, it converts the img into a canvas element which unbinds the hover events, you'll need some way of either rebind the events, or starting with a canvas element.

## Solution

Using a different plugin makes it a piece of cake. [You can download it here.](http://code.google.com/p/jqueryrotate/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#img").live('mouseenter', function() {
        $('#img').rotate(43);
    });
    $("img").live('mouseleave', function() {
        $('#img').rotate(-43);
    });
});
```

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Toukakoukan/e5Jsp/1/)

Comment: I had also come up with that same solution. however once demo'd you will see the image just twirls and twirls.

Comment: If you actually look at my jsFiddle demo, you'll see it doesn't because I'm using a **different plugin**. Not in Chrome at any rate...

Comment: Ok seems to have something to do with doctype aand/or compatibility mode. Thanks IE

Comment: Why did you accept the other chaps answer out of interest? Just wondering :)

Comment: Actually I have run into the issue that both techniques work under FF but neither works for me under IE9 (yet). The image that I am rotating is placed with a position:relative css tag and under IE the image moves from the initial location to the end of the content area, which is not what I need. Soo still searching for the right combo.

Comment: Ok the latest issue was resolved with setting the correct DocType.

Answer (score 3):

as stated above this can be done using `.hover()`

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("#img").hover(
    function () {
      $(this).rotate(43); 
    },
    function () {
      $(this).rotate(-43); 
    }
  );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Well right off the bat.

```
 $("img").bind('mouseleave', function () {
        $('#img').rotate(-43);              
    });
```

should be

```
 $("#img").bind('mouseleave', function () {
            $('#img').rotate(-43);              
        });
```